# How do I extract data from MySQL and display it on a webpage with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to extract data from MySQL and display it on my HTML page
Here is my code in server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");


const products = require("./utils/products.js");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use("/products", products);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hei");
})

const PORT = 5000;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';



app.listen(PORT, HOST,() => console.log(`Server running on ${HOST}:${PORT}`));
```

Here is my code in HTML:

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
  <div class="card border-0 bg-light mb-2">
   <div class="card-body">
    <img src="vintage.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
  <h6>Vintage Two Piece Set</h6>
  <p>$39.99</p>
  <button>View Details</button>
 </div>
```

I want to get the name of the product and the price from MySQL database and display it on my html page as you can see below on the image:
[Product data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyEaN.png)

How can I do that using Node.js and express.

So basically I want to get the data of the products on my HTML as soon as i run my webproject.

Thanks on behalf!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ORM to access your database easier (I like to use `typeORM` on node apps), and use `hbs` to use `MVC` on your app, só you can access yoour node app and dispay data in the same application.